# How do I set existing Word 2010 Fluent Ribbon buttons to a fixed size, rather than having them automatically scaled to "large"?

Tags: microsoft-word, ribbon

I'm reconfiguring a ribbon in Word 2010 to include existing buttons, but they are large in the UI. How do I make them small icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there's an attribute called Autoscale in the  element that is set to TRUE by default. It stretches things out to fill the space at the expense of other ribbon groups.

Answer (score 1):

See these articles

http://wordribbon.tips.net/Pages/T009036_Adjusting_the_Size_of_Ribbon_Icons.html

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/67/10208042/office-2010-the-ribbon-icons-are-suddenly-very-big.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the ribbon and select "Customize the ribbon," you can create custom "groups" of buttons to place on any of the tabs (or even create your own custom tabs). While still in the customization box, right click on your custom group and click "Hide command labels." Now those buttons in that group will be small.